# Winform how to remove Item from combobox using SelectedValue?

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

```
      public void Fill()
      {
        cmb1.DataSource = dt;
        cmb1.DisplayMember = "Name";
        cmb1.ValueMember = "ID";
      }

     public void Remove()//by Text
     {
            string selectedItem ="Jack";
            cmb1.Items.Remove(selectedItem );
     }

     public void Remove()//by Value
     {
            string selectedvalue ="10";
            cmb1.Items.RemoveAt(selectedvalue);

     }
```

This Code used but not worked. 
Not Remove Using Value or Text.Or Any Other Methods to fill combobox without DataSource.

Comment: I modified my answer. If you manually fill the comboBox with objects you can achieve that by a simple: cmb1.Items.Remove(cmb1.SelectedItem);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following because you are using a data source:

```
DataTable dt = (DataTable)cmb1.DataSource;
dt.Rows.RemoveAt(cmb1.SelectedIndex);
```

Comment: This is assuming you are not sorting/filtering the combobox after you attach the source.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
class Student {
        public int ID{get;set;}
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // You override this method depending in what you want to show on the comboBox as text
        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name;
        }
    }

    private void fillComboBox(List<Student> students)
    {
        // We manually fill the comboBox Items; The displayed text is going to be define by the ToString() method this object has define
        students.ForEach(x => cmb1.Items.Add(students));
    }
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // We can remove the items by just doing this
        cmb1.Items.Remove(cmb1.SelectedItem);
    }
```

Comment: No you can't.  The ComboBox is using a DataSource, so you would have to remove the item from the DataSource.

Comment: Yes ,I try but error invoke --Additional information: Items collection cannot be modified when the DataSource property is set.

Comment: I modified my answer, to do it without depending on a DataSource. Fill the comboBox items manually with your objects, override the ToString() method of this object's class. I modified my answer BTW, using Student as an example class.